# How to find summation of roots in a transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find summation of roots in a transcendental equation, I need to substitute the parameter β that takes on values on the log scale.

```
β = {0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100}
eqns = Subscript[α, n]*BesselJ[1, Subscript[α, n]] == #*
     BesselJ[0, Subscript[α, n]] & /@ β
roots = FindRoot[#, {Subscript[α, n], 1}] & /@ eqns

{{αn→0.141245},{αn→0.441682},{αn→1.25578},{αn→2.1795},{αn→2.3809}}
```

I managed to get the initial value of the roots, however when there is summation I don't know how to ask Mathematica when to use the initial root and summation of the roots.

```
β = {0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100}
eqns = Subscript[α, n]*BesselJ[1, Subscript[α, n]] == #*
         BesselJ[0, Subscript[α, n]] & /@ β
roots = FindRoot[#, {Subscript[α, n], 1}] & /@ eqns  
find = Sum[(Subscript[a, n]^2 - Subscript[a, m]^2), {m, 1, 4}] /. 
      roots
```

Somehow, manually it looked like this

```
 β = 0.01, α, n = 0.1412, α, m = 0.1412 + ....+.....+.... 
 β = 0.1,  α, n = 0.4417, α, m = 0.4417 + ....+.....+....
 β = 1,    α, n = 1.2558, α, m = 1.2558 + ....+.....+....
 β = 10,   α, n = 2.1795, α, m = 2.1795 + ....+.....+....
 β = 100,  α, n = 2.3809, α, m = 2.3809 + ....+.....+....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure that I completely understand what you are after. However, try this:

```
eqns = Table[
  Subscript[\[Alpha], n]*
    BesselJ[1, Subscript[\[Alpha], n]] == \[Beta][[n]]*
    BesselJ[0, Subscript[\[Alpha], n]], {n, 1, 5}]



(*  {BesselJ[1, Subscript[\[Alpha], 1]] Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] == 
      0.01 BesselJ[0, Subscript[\[Alpha], 1]], 
     BesselJ[1, Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]] Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] == 
      0.1 BesselJ[0, Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]], 
     BesselJ[1, Subscript[\[Alpha], 3]] Subscript[\[Alpha], 3] == 
      BesselJ[0, Subscript[\[Alpha], 3]], 
     BesselJ[1, Subscript[\[Alpha], 4]] Subscript[\[Alpha], 4] == 
      10 BesselJ[0, Subscript[\[Alpha], 4]], 
     BesselJ[1, Subscript[\[Alpha], 5]] Subscript[\[Alpha], 5] == 
      100 BesselJ[0, Subscript[\[Alpha], 5]]}  *)

roots = Table[
  FindRoot[eqns[[n]], {Subscript[\[Alpha], n], 1}], {n, 1, 5}]

 (*   {{Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] -> 0.141245}, {Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] -> 
       0.441682}, {Subscript[\[Alpha], 3] -> 
       1.25578}, {Subscript[\[Alpha], 4] -> 2.1795}, {Subscript[\[Alpha], 
       5] -> 2.3809}} *)

find[n_] := Sum[(roots[[n, 1, 2]]^2 - roots[[m, 1, 2]]^2), {m, 1, 4}]
```

This is the second solution:

```
find[2]
```

(*   -5.7619  *)

This makes a table of solutions:

```
lst = Join[{{"\[Beta]", "find"}}, 
   Table[{\[Beta][[n]], find[n]}, {n, 1, 5}]];
Grid[lst, Dividers -> All]
```

yielding the following:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot. However when I tried to duplicate the roots=Table.... , it appeared error and I did not get like yours.

Comment: Did you copy-paste or retyped?

Comment: Well, it works fine for me (Mma 12.0, Win10). Take care that in your original code, you have written the letter "a" instead of "alpha" in one place. That potentially could be one reason if you used parts of your code together with mine.

Comment: Thanks I managed to replicate but can I know the meaning find[2]. As you can see there will  be 5 roots because the parameter \[Beta] is changing from {0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100} but why the final answer only -5.7619, supposedly should be 5 answers also eg. {-5.7619, 0.1, 1, 10, 100}

Comment: Yes, you can. `find[n]` is a function of `n`. The latter takes values from 1 to 5. `find[2]` calculates the result number 2.  By substituting various values of n you find other results.

Comment: Thanks sir but is there any way I could find the values of the summation separately. I mean when the parameter [Beta] = 0.01, the value of the summation is .... and when [Beta] = 0.1, the value of the summation is ....  Eg. like I  showed in the table above manually

Comment: Please see the edit I've written.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir :)